# build_association working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models with a one-to-one association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :setting
end

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Each model has plenty of fields and user is used quite extensively by a non rails external server, which is why I have separated the tables.

I am trying to use the build_association but all I get is undefined method `build_setting' for nil:NilClass. I want to do this because I want a single form with fields from both models to setup a new user.

In my user controllers new method I try this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @setting = @user.setting.build_setting

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
  end
end
```

Which throws:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#new
  undefined method `build_setting' for nil:NilClass
```

Why? According to the api docs this is the way to do it.

Doing this seems to work, but its not the right way (or is it?):

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @setting = Setting.new
  @user.setting=@setting

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
  end
end
```

Comment: But you're calling `build_setting` on the results of getting the new user's `setting`, which doesn't exist yet. I'm pretty sure the documentation doesn't say *exactly* what you're trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your users model add

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :setting
  validates_associated :setting
end
```

and then use

```
@setting = @user.build_setting
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
@setting = @user.build_setting
```

This is after an edit, so if you like this answer, accept Mahesh's below.

Comment: Also, you might have to declare accepts_nested_attributes on the user class to get those methods, though I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: @setting=@user.build  generates:                            NoMethodError in UsersController#new

undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes make no difference. I am running rails 3.0.7 for this app.

Comment: @RutgerKarlsson Same reason as my original comment: you can't call a method on a `nil` value, which is what `setting` will be before it's been set. I don't know why this answer believes that would work.

Comment: you say in your first comment here <pre>@setting=@user.build</pre>. that is NOT what I said to do: <pre>@setting = @user.setting.build</pre>.  And @Dave Newton. I'm DOING this right now. It works. Rails is smart about using method_missing and other tricks to enforce convention over configuration.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using this on a one to many association this morning. So Dave is entirely correct. if you do user.build_setting as Mahesh says below, it works in 3.0.*

Comment: @jaydel There's no missing method in `@user.setting.build`, there's a missing property, if it hasn't been set.

Comment: Agreed. see my above comment, and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *Whew* thought I was going nuts ;)